# Find a particular integral for $y''+y'+y = 2+x+\cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If it were merely $y''+y'+y = \cos(x)$, then I know that I would try $a\cos(kx) + b\sin(kx)$, but with the added $2 + x$, I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to add $ax+b$ for the part $2+x$ of the right side. So a particular solution would be of the form $ax+b+c\cos(x)+d\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also treat this kind of equations ($y"+y'+y=f(x)+g(x)$) the following way:

Find the solution $y_1$ for $y"+y'+y=f(x)$ and the solution $y_2$ for $y"+y'+y=g(x)$.

Then your solution is $y=y_1+y_2$

Beware! This does not mean this is always the best way to solve such an equation... But since you are dealing with LINEAR equations, you can use that fact!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for every term independently.

For $2$ you obviously have $2''+2'+2=2$.

For $x$, try $x$ itself, which gives $x''+x'+x=1+x\ne x$. But the fix is easy: $x-1$ yields $(x-1)''+(x-1)'+(x-1)=x$. (More generally, for a given polynomial of degree $d$, try an arbitrary polynomial of degree $d$.)

For the cosine, it is convenient to use the complex representation and consider the real part of $e^{ix}$.

We have $(e^{ix})''+(e^{ix})'+e^{ix}=(i^2+i+1)e^{ix}=ie^{ix}$ so that the solution is the real part of $-ie^{ix}$ or $\sin x$.

Hence

$$x+1+\sin x.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y''+y'+y = 2+x+\cos(x)$$
The characteristic polynomial is
$$r^2+r+1=0 \implies  r=\frac {-1\pm i\sqrt 3}2$$
$$\implies y=e^{-1/2}(c_1 \cos(\sqrt 3 x/2)+c_2 \sin(\sqrt 3x/2))$$ 
So  for $\cos(x)$ try $a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)$ it gives $\sin(x)$

And $ax+b$ for $x+1$
$$a+ax+b=x+2 \implies (a,b)=(1,1)$$
Therefore 
 $$\implies y=e^{-1/2}(c_1 \cos( \frac {\sqrt 3}2x)+c_2 \sin( \frac {\sqrt 3}2x)+x+1+\sin(x)$$